# PHP Mail() Base64 sends emails as encoded text

Tags: php, ubuntu, base64

Just migrated site to a new server. After migration, php mail() sends out emails that are encoded in text and are unintelligible. After doing some research, it seems that this may be an issue with base64? I am not sure how the new setup may have caused the old previously working email templates to no longer work. Old setup was Open Solaris, new one is Ubuntu 10.04. Message output:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

MIME-Version: 1.0
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
Message-Id: <20120427211219.E50AE1C83A@li439-167.members.linode.com>
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2012 17:12:19 -0400 (EDT)
X-pstn-dkim: 0 skipped:not-enabled

PHA+RGVhciBNciBSaWNoYXJkIEVicmlnaHQsPC9wPgoKPHA+VGhhbmsgeW91IHZlcnkgbXVjaCBm

b3Igc3VibWl0dGluZyBhIHNwZWNpYWwgYXBwbGljYXRpb24gdG8gSGFydmFyZApOYXRpb25hbCBN

b2RlbCBVbml0ZWQgTmF0aW9ucyAyMDEzLjwvcD4KCjxwPldlIGFyZSB2ZXJ5IHBsZWFzZWQgdG8g

YXNzaWduIHlvdSB0aGUgZm9sbG93aW5nIHBvc2l0aW9uOjxiciAvPgpBc3NpZ25tZW50OiBMYXJy

eSBQYWdlIChDRU8pPGJyIC8+CkNvbW1pdHRlZTogWmFwYXRhJiMwMzk7cyBDYW1wLCAxOTExPC9w

PgoKPHA+V2UgcmVjZWl2ZWQgYSBsYXJnZSBudW1iZXIgb2YgYXBwbGljYXRpb25zIHRoaXMgeWVh

ciBhbmQgaGF2ZSBkb25lCm91ciB2ZXJ5IGJlc3QgdG8gYWNjb21tb2RhdGUgeW91ciBwcmVmZXJl

bmNlcy4gUGxlYXNlIG5vdGUgdGhhdCBhbGwKYXNzaWdubWVudCBkZWNpc2lvbnMgYXJlIGZpbmFs

LgoKVGhpcyBhc3NpZ25tZW50IGlzIG5vdyByZWZsZWN0ZWQgaW4geW91ciBhY2NvdW50IGluIG91

ciA8YQpocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbXVuYmFzZS5obm11bi5vcmciPm9ubGluZSByZWdpc3RyYXRpb24g

c3lzdGVtPC9hPiwgd2hpY2gKeW91IGNhbiBhY2Nlc3MgdXNpbmcgdGhlIHNhbWUgbG9nLWluIGFu

ZCBwYXNzd29yZCB5b3UgdXNlZCB0bwpyZWdpc3Rlci4KIFBsZWFzZSB2aXNpdCA8YSBocmVmPSJo

dHRwOi8vd3d3LmhubXVuLm9yZyI+d3d3LmhubXVuLm9yZzwvYT4gZm9yCm1vcmUgaW5mb3JtYXRp

b24gYWJvdXQgeW91ciBjb21taXR0ZWUuPC9wPgo8cD5QbGVhc2Ugbm90ZSB0aGF0IHlvdSBhcmUg

cmVxdWlyZWQgdG8gc3VibWl0IHlvdXIgJDc1IGRlbGVnYXRlIGZlZQpubyBsYXRlciB0aGFuIDEg

RGVjZW1iZXIgMjAxMi4gV2l0aG91dCB0aGUgcGF5bWVudCBvZiB5b3VyIGRlbGVnYXRlCmZlZSwg

d2UgcmVzZXJ2ZSB0aGUgcmlnaHQgdG8gcmVhc3NpZ24geW91ciBwb3NpdGlvbiB0byBhbm90aGVy

CmRlbGVnYXRlLjwvcD4KPHA+SWYgeW91IGhhdmUgYW55IHF1ZXN0aW9ucyBvciBjb25jZXJucywg

cGxlYXNlIGZlZWwgZnJlZSB0byBlbWFpbApvdXIgc3RhZmYgYXQgPGEgaHJlZj0ibWFpbHRvOmlu

Zm9AaG5tdW4ub3JnIj5pbmZvQGhubXVuLm9yZzwvYT4uIFdlCmxvb2sgZm9yd2FyZCB0byBzZWVp

bmcgeW91IGF0IEhOTVVOIDIwMTMgaW4gRmVicnVhcnkhPC9wPgoKCgo8cD5TaW5jZXJlbHksPGJy

IC8+CkdpbGxpYW4gVC4gRmFycmVsbDxiciAvPgpTZWNyZXRhcnktR2VuZXJhbDxiciAvPgpIYXJ2

YXJkIE5hdGlvbmFsIE1vZGVsIFVuaXRlZCBOYXRpb25zIDIwMTM8L3A+Cg==
```

Thanks for the help! Long time user, first time poster. Hoping to give back more to the StackOverflow community.

**Edit:** Yii extension(?) that handles mail sending.

```
<?php
/**
 * Email class file.
 * 
 * @author Jonah Turnquist <poppitypop@gmail.com>
 * @link http://php-thoughts.cubedwater.com/
 * @version 1.0
 */
class Email extends CApplicationComponent {
/**
 * @var string Type of email.  Options include "text/html" and "text/plain"
 */
public $type = 'text/html';
/**
 * @var string Receiver, or receivers of the mail.
 */
public $to = null;

/**
 * @var string Email subject
 */
public $subject = '';

/**
 * @var string from address
 */
public $from = null;

/**
 * @var string Reply-to address
 */
public $replyTo = null;

/**
 * @var string Return-path address
 */
public $returnPath = null;

/**
 * @var string Carbon Copy
 *
 * List of email's that should receive a copy of the email.
 * The Recipient WILL be able to see this list
 */
public $cc = null;

/**
 * @var string Blind Carbon Copy
 *
 * List of email's that should receive a copy of the email.
 * The Recipient WILL NOT be able to see this list
 */
public $bcc = null;

/**
 * @var string Main content
 */
public $message = '';

/**
 * @var string Delivery type.  If set to 'php' it will use php's mail() function, and if set to 'debug'
 * it will not actually send it but output it to the screen
 */
public $delivery = 'php';

/**
 * @var string language to encode the message in (eg "Japanese", "ja", "English", "en" and "uni" (UTF-8))
 */
public $language= 'uni';

/**
 * @var string the content-type of the email
 */
public $contentType= 'utf-8';

/**
 * @var string The view to use as the content of the email, as an alternative to setting $this->message.
 * Must be located in application.views.email directory.  This email object is availiable within the view
 * through $email, thus letting you define things such as the subject within the view (helps maintain 
 * seperation of logic and output).
 */
public $view = null;

/**
 * @var array Variable to be sent to the view.
 */
public $viewVars = null;    

/**
 * @var string The layout for the view to be imbedded in. Must be located in
 * application.views.email.layouts directory.  Not required even if you are using a view
 */
public $layout = null;

/**
 * @var integer line length of email as per RFC2822 Section 2.1.1
 */
public $lineLength = 70;

public function __construct() {
    Yii::setPathOfAlias('email', dirname(__FILE__).'/views');
}

  /**
   * Model United Nations Specific sending function.
   */
  public function quick($subject, $view, $to, $info=null, $cc=null) {
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->from = 'ADDRESS REMOVED';
$this->to = $to;
if ($cc) $this->cc = $cc;
$this->bcc = 'ADDRESS REMOVED';
$this->view = $view;
$this->send($info);
  }

/**
 * Sends email.
 * @param mixed the content of the email, or variables to be sent to the view.
 * If not set, it will use $this->message instead for the content of the email
 */
public function send($arg1=null) {
    if ($this->view !== null) {
        if ($arg1 == null)
            $vars = $this->viewVars;
        else
            $vars = $arg1;

        $view = Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('application.views.email.'.$this->view, array_merge($vars, array('email'=>$this)), true);
        if ($this->layout === null) {
            $message = $view;
        } else {
            $message = Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('application.views.email.layouts.'.$this->layout, array('content'=>$view), true);
        }
    } else {
        if ($arg1 === null) {
            $message = $this->message;
        } else {
            $message = $arg1;
        }
    }

    //process 'to' attribute
    $to = $this->processAddresses($this->to);
    return $this->mail($to, $this->subject, $message);
}

private function mail($to, $subject, $message) {
    switch ($this->delivery) {
        case 'php':
            $message = wordwrap($message, $this->lineLength);
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
            mb_language($this->language);
            return mb_send_mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $this->createHeaders()), '-fmunbase@ADDRESS.org');
        case 'debug':
            $debug = Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('email.debug',
                    array_merge(compact('to', 'subject', 'message'), array('headers'=>$this->createHeaders())),
                    true);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('email', $debug);
            break;
    }
}
private function createHeaders() {
    $headers = array();

    //maps class variable names to header names
    $map = array(
        'from' => 'From',
        'cc' => 'Cc',
        'bcc' => 'Bcc',
        'replyTo' => 'Reply-To',
        'returnPath' => 'Return-Path',
    );
    foreach ($map as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($this->$key))
            $headers[] = "$value: {$this->processAddresses($this->$key)}";
    }
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: {$this->type}; charset=".$this->contentType;
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";

    return $headers;
}
private function processAddresses($addresses) {
    return (is_array($addresses)) ? implode(', ', $addresses) : $addresses;
}
}
```

Comment: what happens if you write the "base64" word in lowercase and put it just before the message?

Comment: Please can we see your PHP code? The message itself is a valid base64 encoded string, I think @tpaksu might be on to something with the casing of the `BASE64` in the header value, it is normally `base64` - do you see the entire text above in the mail client or just the nonsense text? If you see the headers as well, I think you probably have some extra line breaks leaking in there.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find where the header value is being set. Truth be told, I did not write the code for this Yii-based web app that I am now helping to migrate, and do not know what the original engineer did. I have edited the question with possibly relevant configuration files for the email scripts.

Comment: That blank line between the `Content-Type` and `MIME-Version` header lines shouldn't be there. Is that actually like that, or is it a copy-paste issue? Similarly, not sure there are supposed to be lines between the pieces of base64 encoded text.

Comment: The lines are actually there in the message. Although I am not sure why the lines would be inserted. There is no line break between the two in the extension config file (9 lines from the bottom in the second code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the extra line returns were the culprit. The original (buggy version) message header is excerpted below:

```
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:Email.php
From: Harvard National Model United Nations 2013 <info@hnmun.org>

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
```

And was caused by the implode command in the extension control:

```
private function mail($to, $subject, $message) {
switch ($this->delivery) {
    case 'php':
        $message = wordwrap($message, $this->lineLength);
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        mb_language($this->language);
        return mb_send_mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $this->createHeaders()), '-fmunbase@ADDRESS.org');
    case 'debug':
        $debug = Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('email.debug',
                array_merge(compact('to', 'subject', 'message'), array('headers'=>$this->createHeaders())),
                true);
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('email', $debug);
        break;
}
```

Turns out it needed an argument of `implode("\n", $this->createHeaders())` instead of `implode("\r\n", $this->createHeaders())`
Something to do with a new version of PHP or the new OS perhaps? Thank you all for your help!